# bottom-align a link in a div

Tags: html, css

I have something similar to this

```
.col {float: left; width:190px;border: 1px solid red;}

<div class="col">
    <p>some text goes here some ass sasass here </p
</div>
<div class="col">
   <p>some text goes here</p>
   <a href="">Link</a>
</div>
```

So the text on the first div is quite long where as the text in the second div is not. So the first div gets taller than the second div.

What I want to achieve is leave the text in the second column as it is but vertical align the link to the bottom to match the left's div height.

Does that make sense?

Thanks

Comment: do you specify width 2 times on purpose?

Comment: Google with "CSS equal height columns".

Comment: yes the width has to be the same on both columns.

Comment: you can't specify 2 width on the same css class.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't see that. The width has to be set once only of course. I've just edited the code

Comment: jQuery an option ? It's usually the route I take with these "position something based on an unknown random height" issues

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:
http://www.ejeliot.com/samples/equal-height-columns/example-6.html

added:
you should take out the element that you want to put on the bottom.

```
<div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor 1</p>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>

<div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor 2</p>
</div>
<div class="bottom">
    <a href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah I see that, but how do you align the text on the left column to the bottom?

Comment: post your whole working code, then maybe we can take a look at it correctly